# How do make a dominance using python in set?

Tags: python

I have problem in mycode. I want to compare value which dominance and not dominance is pruned.
mycode is:

```
def dominan(a,b):
    return any([x < y for (x, y) in zip(a, b)])

p1 =  {('S', 'A', 'C', 'T'): (12, 14, 55, 1, 4), ('S', 'C', 'T'): (10, 12, 44, 5, 3), ('S', 'B', 'D', 'T'): (8, 12, 35, 6, 7)}
p2 = {('S', 'B', 'T'): (7, 3, 30, 4, 4)}
pk = list(p2.keys())
pv = list(p2.values())
pks = list(p1.keys())
pvs = list(p1.values())
for x in range(0, len(pk)):
    if (len(pks) == 0):
        pks.append(pk[x])
        pvs.append(pv[x])
    for l in range(0, len(pks)):
        if dominan(pv[x], pvs[l]):
          pks.append(pk[x])
          pvs.append(pv[x])
res = dict(zip(pks, pvs))
print("result dominance p2 and p1 =", res)
```

The logical is p2 is not dominated by `('S', 'B', 'D', 'T'): (8, 12, 35, 6, 7)` because every value are smaller.

Any can help my problem? Thank you very much..

Comment: what are you trying to do with p1 and p2 dicts and what is your expected result?

Comment: my expected output is: `{('S', 'A', 'C', 'T'): (12, 14, 55, 1, 4), ('S', 'C', 'T'): (10, 12, 44, 5, 3), ('S', 'B', 'T'): (7, 3, 30, 4, 4)}`

Comment: why SBT included and not SBDT?

Comment: because `SBDT` is dominated by `SBT`. `SBDT` is pruned.

Comment: what do you mean by dominated? explain your logic how do you assume SBDT dominates SBT

Comment: `SBDT` have values `(8, 12, 35, 6, 7)` and `SBT` have values `(7, 3, 30, 4, 4)`. every values in `SBT` is smaller than `SBT` or  the algorithm scan every value p2 to all values in p1. all values compare one by one. example: `(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)` < `(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)`. dominance is smaller value. one or more than value if smaller it is dominance :)

Comment: what if e.g. SACT had one value smaller and what if p2 had >1 kv pairs?

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: compare value which dominance and not dominance

I have changed `any(...` to `all(...`.

```
    for p2_key, p2_value in p2.items():
        for p1_key, p1_value in p1.items():
            d = [x < y for (x, y) in zip(p2_value, p1_value)]
            print('{}'.format(d))

            if all(d):
                res.append({p2_key: p2_value})
            else:
                res.append({p1_key:p1_value})

    print('dominance:{}'.format(res))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> [True, True, True, True, False]
> [True, True, True, False, False]
> [True, True, True, True, True]
> dominance:[{('S', 'C', 'T'): (10, 12, 44, 5, 3)}, 
>            {('S', 'A', 'C', 'T'): (12, 14, 55, 1, 4)}, 
>            {('S', 'B', 'T'): (7, 3, 30, 4, 4)}]
> ```